# Accessing functions declared in another class

Tags: c++, class

I have a main Game class that handles the game loop for my project, and my main function calls the Game class in order to run the program. I also have a screen class that is basically each level. There is also a ScreenManager class that is in charge of switching between each screen. However, the ScreenManager is in the Game class. The issue I am running into is that I need to be able to call the ScreenManager SwitchScreen function to transition to the next screen, but I do not know how to access those functions when I am within another screen (the SplashScreen, for example).

The overall question is, how can I use the function of the ScreenManager, which is an instance in the Game class, from another class (the SplashScreen class)?

Comment: If `SplashScreen` needs to be able to invoke functions on a `ScreenManager` object, then just provide it a pointer to one at construction?

Comment: I did not think to do that.... lemme give it a shot and I'll get back to you!

Comment: IMHO, this is a design-issue. However, a [mcve] would be nice to give more specific advise.

Comment: Example: A signal handler wants to close the instance it belongs to (i.e. `delete this;`). That's a bad idea if the signal handler is a member-function. That's [Harakiri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seppuku) and would result in Undefined Behavior. (`delete this;` is a bad idea in all cases I can imagine.) ;-)

Comment: I made the project in Xcode. Here is a link to the streamlined version that only contains my issue: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16QKpcoXXACHAeV7mktEiS6eWq6OxnG-k